# La app se detiene cuando le doy clic en entrar

Tags: java, android, mysql, login, contraseña

Hola buenas noches estoy intentando hacer un login pero se detiene la app cuando intento meter el usuario y contraseña

supongo que lo unico que necesitan es la clase java login:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv_registrar;
EditText etnombre, etapellidos,etusuario, etcertificacion, etclave;
Button entrar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    etnombre = findViewById(R.id.nom);
    etapellidos = findViewById(R.id.ape);
    etusuario =  findViewById(R.id.usr);
    etcertificacion = findViewById(R.id.cert);
    etclave =  findViewById(R.id.pass);
    entrar=  findViewById(R.id.entrar);



    tv_registrar=findViewById(R.id.tv_registrar);
    tv_registrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { /*enlace de texto registro con activity Registro*/
            Intent intentReg = new Intent(Login.this, Registro.class);
            Login.this.startActivity(intentReg);
        }
    });

    entrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

        final String user_name=etusuario.getText().toString();
        final String password=etclave.getText().toString();

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if (success){  /*SI EL INICIO DE SECION ES EXITOSO TRAERA LOS DATOS DE LA BASE.. */
                        String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                        String user_name = jsonResponse.getString("user_name");
                        String course = jsonResponse.getString("course");
                        String password = jsonResponse.getString("password");


                        /*ENVIAR datos atraves de un activity a otro primer parametro es donde nos enctramos
                         * y el segundo es a donde vamos a enviar la informacion*/
                        Intent intent = new Intent (Login.this, Bienvenido.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name",name);

                        intent.putExtra("user_name",user_name);
                        intent.putExtra("course",course);
                        intent.putExtra("password",password);
                        Login.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }else {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                        builder.setMessage("ERROR EN EL INICIO DE SESION")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                .create().show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        SolicitudDeInicio SolicitudDeInicio = new SolicitudDeInicio(user_name,password,responseListener);

        /*CLASE PARA COMUNICARSE CON VOLLEY*/
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
        queue.add(SolicitudDeInicio);
        }
    });


}
```

}

y el codigo java que conecta con mi base de datos

```
public class SolicitudDeInicio extends StringRequest {


    private static final String SOLICITUD_DE_INICIO_URL = "http://192.168.1.75/Login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public SolicitudDeInicio(String user_name, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, SOLICITUD_DE_INICIO_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("user_name", user_name);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

agradeceria mucho su ayuda ya que soy nuevo programando y todo funciona perfecto pero cuando ingreso el usuario y la contraseña la app se detiene.

gracias

agrego codigo java registro

```
public class Registro extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText etnombre, etapellidos,etusuario, etcertificacion, etcontra;
Button aceptar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);

    etnombre = findViewById(R.id.nom);
    etapellidos = findViewById(R.id.ape);
    etusuario =  findViewById(R.id.usr);
    etcertificacion = findViewById(R.id.cert);
    etcontra =  findViewById(R.id.contra);

    aceptar=  findViewById(R.id.aceptar);
    aceptar.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    final String name=etnombre.getText().toString();
    final String surname=etapellidos.getText().toString();
    final String user_name=etusuario.getText().toString();
    final String course=etcertificacion.getText().toString();
    final String password=etcontra.getText().toString();


    Response.Listener<String> respoListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {



            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                if (success){                                                             /*si el registro es exitoso nos envia a la pagina principal*/
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Registro.this,Login.class);
                    Registro.this.startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registro.this);
                    builder.setMessage("ERROR EN EL REGISTRO")
                            .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                            .create().show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    };
    SolicitudDeRegistro solicitudDeRegistro = new SolicitudDeRegistro(name, surname, user_name, course, password, respoListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Registro.this);

    queue.add(solicitudDeRegistro);
}
```

}

agrego codigo java de registro que conecta con mi base de datos

```
public class SolicitudDeRegistro extends StringRequest {

private static final String SOLICITUD_DE_REGISTRO_URL= "http://192.168.1.75/Register.php";
private Map<String,String> params;
public SolicitudDeRegistro (String name, String surname, String user_name, String course, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener)
{
    super (Method.POST, SOLICITUD_DE_REGISTRO_URL,listener,null);
    params=new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name",name);
    params.put("surname",surname);
    params.put("user_name",user_name);
    params.put("course",course);
    params.put("password",password);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

Gracias :)

Esos son los errores que me marca el Logcat inmediatamente despues de que se cierra la app

```
2018-12-12 16:04:31.960 3604-3604/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2018-12-12 16:04:35.458 6324-6324/? E/libmdmdetect: Failed to open /sys/bus/msm_subsys/devices/subsys0/name: Permission denied
2018-12-12 16:04:36.154 6336-6336/? E/libmdmdetect: Failed to open /sys/bus/msm_subsys/devices/subsys0/name: Permission denied
2018-12-12 16:04:36.893 6354-6354/? E/libmdmdetect: Failed to open /sys/bus/msm_subsys/devices/subsys0/name: Permission denied
2018-12-12 16:05:04.886 6433-6433/? E/libmdmdetect: Failed to open /sys/bus/msm_subsys/devices/subsys0/name: Permission denied
2018-12-12 16:05:06.174 3999-3999/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.VerifyPerSourceInstallationConsentInstallTask.b(86): Package name null is not an installed package
2018-12-12 16:05:08.959 2207-6551/? E/PacketFilter: combine fail
2018-12-12 16:05:09.375 6549-6549/? E/libmdmdetect: Failed to open /sys/bus/msm_subsys/devices/subsys0/name: Permission denied
2018-12-12 16:05:09.847 6625-6625/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.appmanager
2018-12-12 16:05:10.141 6625-6703/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.appmanager.nekodirect
2018-12-12 16:05:10.177 2207-2455/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=1552, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND] ]
2018-12-12 16:05:10.499 6742-6742/? E/GoogleTagManager: Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
2018-12-12 16:05:10.510 6742-6762/? E/GoogleTagManager: Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
2018-12-12 16:05:11.078 6864-6864/? E/CloudUtils: deviceBlackList = 
2018-12-12 16:05:11.079 6864-6864/? E/HWAccelerateUtils: the model supported hw acceleration
2018-12-12 16:05:11.083 6864-6864/? E/b: deviceIdHash = fe18e7b7-2a3b-4d63-b290-4e652461ff4f
2018-12-12 16:05:11.490 6966-6966/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.katana
2018-12-12 16:05:12.713 6966-7089/? E/CompactDiskManagerImpl.cpp: Failed to remove new folder structure directories: No such file or directory
2018-12-12 16:05:13.427 6966-7083/? E/fb4a.BackgroundLocationReportingManager: Starting location collection failed due to PERMISSION_DENIED, will retry when location services returns
2018-12-12 16:05:44.668 6576-6576/com.example.brian.login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.brian.login, PID: 6576
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.brian.login.Login$2.onClick(Login.java:52)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5685)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22481)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
2018-12-12 16:05:44.690 679-783/? E/JavaDumper:FW:  utils.c(256): mkdir (/data/crashdata) failed. File exists
2018-12-12 16:05:44.698 679-783/? E/JavaDumper:FW:  ramdump_framework.c(317): fp is NULL
2018-12-12 16:05:44.698 679-783/? E/JavaDumper:FW:  ramdump_framework.c(498): Read-only file system
2018-12-12 16:05:44.799 679-783/? E/JavaDumper:FW:  JavaDumper.cpp(262): Failed to remove /tmp/dropbox.txt:Unknown error -2
```

Archivo Login xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginVertical="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/simboloborrado"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/usu"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:hint="Usuario"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_marginVertical="15dp"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:hint="Clave"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/entrar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Entrar"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_registrar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="Registrar"
    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"

    />
```

nuevo error

```
2018-12-13 00:44:06.500 2207-3232/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast org.codeaurora.intent.action.ACTION_NETWORK_SPECIFIER_SET from system 2802:com.android.phone/1001 pkg com.android.phone
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:18676)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19250)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:19341)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:505)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2959)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

Comment: Buenas, agrega un toasts en los try-catch (faltan un montón) y así antes de cerrarse la app te dirá que pasa.

Comment: si puedes mira en el logcat el error que lanza cuando detiene la app y nos lo pones, eso ayuda bastante normalmente.

Comment: ya los agregue @kronosXXI

Comment: el error ( E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.brian.login, PID: 6576 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference at com.example.brian.login.Login$2.onClick(Login.java:52) me lo marca aqui  final String user_name=etusuario.getText().toString();

Comment: Podrías agregar el archivo `xml` de `activity_login`?

Comment: por supuesto, ya esta agregada muchas gracias @A.Palacio

Comment: Se esta bloqueando tu app ya que en el archivo .xml tus identificador del EditText usuario lo tienes asignados
de esta forma usu , en tu actividad Login cambia esto: `etusuario =  findViewById(R.id.usr);` 
por esto: `etusuario =  findViewById(R.id.usu);`

Comment: ya realice el cambio pero ahora el boton entrar no hace nada @A.Palacio y agrego el nuevo error que me marca el logcat gracias

Comment: @A.Palacio que puedo hacer con esto?    2018-12-15 00:37:14.506 2253-3863/? E/WifiService: Permission denial: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
2018-12-15 00:37:24.171 23888-23888/? E/FlurryAgent: Listener cannot be null
  sobre todo con el listener can't be null que esta en el codigo de conexion a mi base de datos de registro y de login